# Cannot read property '0' of undefined in mdbreact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mdbreact

Hey guys I'm using mdbreact to make a cart but I got some errors.
I'm using code from this section: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/sections/e-commerce/
Here my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import {  MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBCard, MDBCardImage, MDBCardBody, MDBCardTitle, MDBCardText, MDBCardFooter, MDBIcon, MDBTooltip } from "mdbreact";

const Item = () => {
  return (
    <section className="text-center my-5">
      <h2 className="h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center my-5">
        Our bestsellers
      </h2>
      <p className="grey-text text-center w-responsive mx-auto mb-5">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit,
        error amet numquam iure provident voluptate esse quasi, veritatis
        totam voluptas nostrum quisquam eum porro a pariatur veniam.
      </p>
      <MDBRow>
        <MDBCol lg="3" md="6" className="mb-lg-0 mb-4">
          <MDBCard cascade narrow ecommerce>
            <MDBCardImage
              cascade
              src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-commerce/Vertical/1.jpg"
              top
              alt="sample photo"
              overlay="white-slight"
            />
            <MDBCardBody cascade className="text-center">
              <a href="#!" className="grey-text">
                <h5>Denim</h5>
              </a>
              <MDBCardTitle>
                <strong>
                  <a href="#!">Denim trousers</a>
                </strong>
              </MDBCardTitle>
              <ul className="rating">
                <li>
                  <MDBIcon icon="star" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <MDBIcon icon="star" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <MDBIcon icon="star" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <MDBIcon icon="star" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <MDBIcon far icon="star" />
                </li>
              </ul>
              <MDBCardText>
                Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit.
              </MDBCardText>
              <MDBCardFooter className="px-1">
                <span className="float-left font-weight-bold">
                  <strong>49$</strong>
                </span>
                <span className="float-right">
                  <MDBTooltip
                    placement="top"
                    tag="a"
                    component="i"
                    componentClass="fa fa-shopping-cart grey-text ml-3"
                    tooltipContent="Add to cart"
                  />
                  <MDBTooltip
                    placement="top"
                    tag="a"
                    component="i"
                    componentClass="fa fa-share-alt grey-text ml-3"
                    tooltipContent="Share"
                  />
                  <MDBTooltip
                    placement="top"
                    tag="a"
                    component="i"
                    className="active"
                    componentClass="fa fa-heart ml-3"
                    tooltipContent="Added to watchlist"
                  />
                </span>
              </MDBCardFooter>
            </MDBCardBody>
          </MDBCard>
        </MDBCol>
       
       
      </MDBRow>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Item;
```

The log says 
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.
Is this an issue from mdbreact or something ? 
If true, can someone suggest me other alternative UI library for reactjs please ? React Bootstrap doesn't look good to me since I'm bad at CSS. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your implementation of `MDBTooltip`. From [the documentation](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/advanced/tooltips/), it appears that component needs two children, the first being what the tooltip is attached to, and the second the content. [Click here for a working example which implements the following code](https://react-qlcser.stackblitz.io)

```
import React from "react";
import { MDBBtn, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBCard, MDBCardImage, MDBCardBody, MDBCardTitle, MDBCardText, MDBCardFooter, MDBIcon, MDBTooltip } from "mdbreact";

const Item = () => {
  return (
    <section className="text-center my-5">
      <h2 className="h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center my-5">
        Our bestsellers
      </h2>
      <p className="grey-text text-center w-responsive mx-auto mb-5">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit,
        error amet numquam iure provident voluptate esse quasi, veritatis
        totam voluptas nostrum quisquam eum porro a pariatur veniam.
      </p>
      <MDBRow>
        <MDBCol lg="3" md="6" className="mb-lg-0 mb-4">
          <MDBCard cascade narrow ecommerce>
            <MDBCardImage
              cascade
              src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/E-commerce/Vertical/1.jpg"
              top
              alt="sample photo"
              overlay="white-slight"
            />
            <MDBCardBody cascade className="text-center">
              <a href="#!" className="grey-text">
                <h5>Denim</h5>
              </a>
              <MDBCardTitle>
                <strong>
                  <a href="#!">Denim trousers</a>
                </strong>
              </MDBCardTitle>
              <ul className="rating">
                <li>
                  <MDBIcon icon="star" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <MDBIcon icon="star" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <MDBIcon icon="star" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <MDBIcon icon="star" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <MDBIcon far icon="star" />
                </li>
              </ul>
              <MDBCardText>
                Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit.
              </MDBCardText>
              <MDBCardFooter className="px-1">
                <span className="float-left font-weight-bold">
                  <strong>49$</strong>
                </span>
                <span className="float-right">
                  <MDBTooltip
                    placement="top"
                    tag="a"
                    component="i"
                    componentClass="fa fa-shopping-cart grey-text ml-3"
                    tooltipContent="Add to cart"
                  >
                    <MDBBtn>Tooltip button</MDBBtn>
                    <div>
                      Tooltip content
                    </div>
                  </MDBTooltip>
                  <MDBTooltip
                    placement="top"
                    tag="a"
                    component="i"
                    componentClass="fa fa-share-alt grey-text ml-3"
                    tooltipContent="Share"
                  >
                  <MDBBtn>Tooltip button</MDBBtn>
                    <div>
                      Tooltip content
                    </div>
                  </MDBTooltip>
                  <MDBTooltip
                    placement="top"
                    tag="a"
                    component="i"
                    className="active"
                    componentClass="fa fa-heart ml-3"
                    tooltipContent="Added to watchlist"
                  >
                  <MDBBtn>Tooltip button</MDBBtn>
                    <div>
                      Tooltip  content
                    </div>
                  </MDBTooltip>
                </span>
              </MDBCardFooter>
            </MDBCardBody>
          </MDBCard>
        </MDBCol>
      </MDBRow>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Item;
```

Comment: I've tried another example without tooltip and it's still the same error

Comment: @聖杯ツグミ I updated my answer to include all your code with the corrections I suggested. Click the link to see it functioning.